# Why can't I see the constraint on this label?

Tags: swift, uiview, uilabel

I'm subclassing an UIView, and I want to add a constraint inside it. But when I do this, I'm not able to add any constraint :

```
class A19: UIView {
let titleLabel : UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "test"
    label.textColor = .white
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

init() {
    super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 414, height: 250))
    backgroundColor = .black
    addSubview(titleLabel)
    titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    titleLabel.sizeToFit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

What's wrong with that?

edit : So I'm putting the playground so everyone see that I'm not crazy !
[image]

Comment: this looks okay ... how are you adding it as a subview?

Comment: Nope, just playing in the playground… Take a look at my edit.

Comment: This line: `titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true` Equal to the top anchor of what? `self`? `view`? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view works.  In the playground, you need to add:

```
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

after creating the view to kick *Auto Layout* into action.